# Google Calendar API Error 405

Tags: c#, api, google-calendar-api

I was trying out the Google Calendar API from [this sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196548/Managing-Google-Calendar-Events-using-NET) but I am getting the following error:

```
Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 405

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 405
```

Stack Trace:

Stack Trace:

> [GDataRequestException: Execution of authentication request returned
>   unexpected result: 405]
>   _2.BusinessLogicLayer.LogicClasses.LeaveLogic.AddToGoogleCalendar() in C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\Development\Ticketing
>   system\2.BusinessLogicLayer\LogicClasses\LeaveLogic.cs:375
>   _1.PresentationLayer.WebPages.LeaveRequest.tstbtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\Development\Ticketing
>   system\1.PresentationLayer\WebPages\LeaveRequest.aspx.cs:403
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553594
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +103
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724

Code:

```
string sGoogleUserName = "******@gmail.com";
            string sGooglePassword = "*****";
            Uri oCalendarUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + sGoogleUserName + "/private/full");

            //Initialize Calendar Service
            CalendarService oCalendarService = new CalendarService("CalendarSampleApp");
            oCalendarService.setUserCredentials(sGoogleUserName, sGooglePassword);

            //Use Proxy 
            GDataRequestFactory oRequestFactory = (GDataRequestFactory)oCalendarService.RequestFactory;
            WebProxy oWebProxy = new WebProxy(WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(oCalendarUri));
            oWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            oWebProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            oRequestFactory.Proxy = oWebProxy;


            //Set Event Entry 
            EventEntry oEventEntry = new EventEntry();
            oEventEntry.Title.Text = "Test Calendar Entry From .Net";
            oEventEntry.Content.Content = "Hurrah!!! I posted my first Google calendar event through .Net";

            //Set Event Location 
            Where oEventLocation = new Where();
            oEventLocation.ValueString = "New Zealand";
            oEventEntry.Locations.Add(oEventLocation);

            //Set Event Time
            When oEventTime = new When(new DateTime(2011, 5, 31, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(2011, 5, 31, 9, 0, 0).AddHours(1));
            oEventEntry.Times.Add(oEventTime);

            //Set Additional Properties
            ExtendedProperty oExtendedProperty = new ExtendedProperty();
            oExtendedProperty.Name = "SynchronizationID";
            oExtendedProperty.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            oEventEntry.ExtensionElements.Add(oExtendedProperty);

            // CalendarService oCalendarService = GAuthenticate();

            //Prevents This Error
            //{"The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation failed."}
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            //Save Event
            oCalendarService.Insert(oCalendarUri, oEventEntry);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment the Proxy part it should work:

```
////Use Proxy 
//GDataRequestFactory oRequestFactory = (GDataRequestFactory)oCalendarService.RequestFactory;
//WebProxy oWebProxy = new WebProxy(WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(oCalendarUri));
//oWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; //oWebProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
//oRequestFactory.Proxy = oWebProxy;
```